Optimal way to process messages from Kafka in Python
Everyone 
I am new to Kafka. I am writing code for a python module that will process messages from Kafka. The module will be containerized using docker. The module will read a Kafka message, do some processing that involves a lot of I/O, and send a kafka message to another topic. This module is expected to receive a lot of messages every second (100 for example). Each message takes about 3 seconds to process, which means I will need a lot of containers to process those messages, but I want to increase the utilization of each container to reduce the number of overall container and reduce the costs. There are two approaches that I thought about:

Concurrent processing using Asyncio.

for msg in KafkaConsumer:
    #call async method to process the msg
    processMSG(msg)
    await processMSG

I do not think this is a very good approach since, it blocks the listener while processMSG  is running.

Use multithreading to process requests parallelly.

I am not sure that my thought process is heading towards the right direction, so I would appreciate it if someone would help guide me towards a better approach that improves the server utilization.

If your constraint is Python, using asyncio is the best approach as it is round robbing the threads for each container while it's on I/O, making it a lot faster than blocking the process until the message has been processed completely.
About multithreading, because you're using asyncio it won't help you boost performance, since the GIL already plays a role when running async actions on Python.
To boost performance, you need to use multiprocessing, while each process listens on different partitions of the topic (to avoid duplications). Same goes for your multiple container instances by the way.
Please note that Python doesn't have a real multithreading, only one thread runs at a single moment, both for the multithreading library and the asyncio. Read about GIL in Python.
On the other hand, if you don't really need to use Python, JavaScript is much more suitable for your need, since it has a non-blocking architecture that will probably speed up your performance.
